# android RestClientException: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found

Tags: android, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am using `spring android rest template` and trying to convert a JSON response into a java class as shown [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html#rest-template-examples).

Here is my snippet trying to do the work:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

    //I have already tried to manually setting converters with no luck
    //List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    //messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    //messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    //messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    //restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    Result result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Result.class);
```

I think I have done everything required as it is told in the document:

- I have following jars in my classpath

  - jackson-all-1.7.6.jar
  - spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.M2.jar
- the `url` really returns a JSON object.
- My `Result` class is a POJO with all the required fields

Basically having the `Jackson dependencies` in my classpath must be enough to get it work as it says:

> The MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is conditionally loaded when you create a new RestTemplate instance. If the Jackson dependencies are found in your classpath, the message converter will be automatically added and available for use in REST operations.

So what I am missing here, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Full exception can be found here:

```
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2083)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2421)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8869)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at xxx.SamplePageActivity.doRest(SamplePageActivity.java:83)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2078)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     ... 11 more
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638): Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [[Lxxx.SamplePageActivity$Result;] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:77)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:449)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:404)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:202)
04-20 04:25:52.706: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9638):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: that's very interesting. I'd love to hear the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done anything on Android but I know converts are picky with Content-Type. For Jackson to work the message body needs to have **'Content-Type: application/json**'. Try to check all headers on the response.

Comment: wow it's been a while and I don't remember exactly how did I fix that but it was something like you suggested, actually I used application/json :)

Comment: I have the same issue, but I can't change content type since my APIs are 3rd party APIs. Is there any alternative other than changing content type?

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same exception and fixed it now.

**Root cause**

At the server, I was setting the response like this:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

**Solution**

I updated the contentType like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error was thrown for a class that would use an enum type instead of a String for a certain property.

The other cause could also be that you are using Jackson 2. You should then change to `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (instead of `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in a similar situation:

> HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); // Sending
>   multipart/form-data
>   requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
>
> // Populate the MultiValueMap being serialized and headers in an
>   HttpEntity object to use for the request
>   HttpEntity> requestEntity = new
>   HttpEntity>(        parts, requestHeaders);
>
> RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
>   restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new
>   FormHttpMessageConverter());
>   restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new
>   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
>
> return restTemplate.postForObject(URI, requestEntity,
>   APIResponseUpload.class);